# Multiboot by UEFI boot manager for Win8.1, Mac OS X and Linux

Tags: macos, windows-8, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader

I am trying to build a hackintosh and want to multi-boot 1) Windows 8  2) Mac OS X and 3) Linux. Each OS will be installed on their own harddisk.

If the motherboard and display card are fully supporting UEFI and GOP respectively. The question is: **is it possible to use the motherboard's UEFI boot manager to multi-boot the 3 OS?**

To be specific, let say the installation process is as below:

1. Three harddisks, name them SSD1, SSD2 & SSD3
2. In the motherboard's UEFI (BIOS) setup, disable SSD2 & SSD3
3. Install win8 on SSD1
4. In the motherboard's UEFI (BIOS) setup, disable SSD1 & SSD3
5. Install Linux on SSD2
6. In the motherboard's UEFI (BIOS) setup, disable SSD1 & SSD2
7. Install hackintosh by clover on SSD3
8. In the motherboard's UEFI (BIOS) setup, enable all SSD1 , 2 & 3
9. Use the UEFI boot manager to choose the EFI boot loader to boot the desired OS

Feasible?

Comment: As far as I know, if your motherboard has UEFI boot enabled, it will look for a UEFI partition on the first hard drive. I haven't seen any instances where it can optionally look for the UEFI partition on slave drives. Using a regular bootloader/boot manager is much simpler, why not do that?

Comment: Because using a UEFI boot manager IMO can hide the fact that this PC is configured to be multiboot, means all OS thought they are the only OS on this PC. I think this can make thing much simpler later.

Comment: @TheJamaicanGuy, I double checked the UEFI spec, UEFI firmware can boot from all drives. From the spec chapter 2. "UEFI allows the consolidation of boot menus from the OS loader and platform firmware into a single platform firmware menu. These platform firmware menus will allow the selection of any UEFI OS loader from any partition on any boot medium that is supported by UEFI boot services."

Comment: That's great. I think I have a better idea of what you're trying to do. With the traditional boot menu, other OS's would know they're installed alongside another os, but with your multiple ssd setup you want each OS to think it's the only one installed on the computer. Makes sense, and I'm pretty sure that's possible. One thing though, couldn't you could use the BIOS boot device selector?